# jQuery Forms: how to pass error to client from a WCF service

Tags: jquery, wcf

I'm trying to pass result of an operation from a WCF service to a client.

My service looks like this

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Upload/{metadata}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        void Upload(string metadata, Stream stream);

        public void Upload(string metadata, Stream stream)
        {
...
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription = e.Message;
            }
        }
```

My client is...

```
<form id="fileUploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fileUploadTitle" name="fileUploadTitle" class="m-wrap" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="file" id="postedFile" name="postedFile" class="m-btn" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="fileUploadButton" name="fileUploadButton" value="Do Upload" class="m-btn" />
        </div>
        <div id="fileUploadResult"></div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#fileUploadButton").click(function () {
            $('form').ajaxSubmit(
            {
                url: '/_vti_bin/UploadService/UploadService.svc/Upload/' + $("#fileUploadTitle").val(),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                beforeSubmit: function () {
                    $("#fileUploadResult").html("Uploading...").css("background", "yellow");
                },
                success: function (r, s, x) {
                    $("#fileUploadResult").html("File uploaded").css("background", "lime");
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#fileUploadResult").html("File not uploaded").css("background", "red");
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Problem is, success is always getting called, no matter whether server throws exception and is setting StatusCode different than 200.

Tried also with FaultException to no avail.

I actually get a response header "Response" of "HTTP/1.1 400 ", but I would like to get the "error" callback being called, and get a full status code...

Suggestions about what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure success is every time called. Because the connection to your web service works and the web service returns the outcome. Your ajax function doesn't know that the web service returns an error because of a problem on the server side. You must parse the return value in your success function and then make rules what to do with it. The error function only gets called when an error between the connection of front end and web service occurs.

Comment: I see, thanks. Any way to get an "error" callback being called? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what kind of return values your service has, but I would just add an additional return parameter that includes an error message. On success of the web service leave it empty, when you catch an error put the error message in. In the success function on the client side you just check then if this parameter is empty or not and based on that make a decision how to proceed with it.